# angularFire $asObject doesn't push

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am new to firebase and trying to use the $asObject as in the angulerFire doc. Basically, I have profile as follows below. I use $asObject to update the email. However when I use $save(), it replaces the entire profile with only the email, rather than pushing it to the end of list ie it works like set() rather than push(). Is how it is meant to work? how do I only push?

Object

```
{profiles:
 {peterpan:
 {name:"Peter Trudy", dob:"7th March"}
 }
}
```

My click function:

```
 $scope.angularObject = function(){
            var syncProfile = $firebase(ref.child("profiles").child("peterpan"));
            var profileObject = syncProfile.$asObject();
            profileObject.email= "peter@peterpan.com";
            profileObject.$save();
         };
```

Comment: $asObject is intended for single records (i.e. objects) where you're attempting to utilize it as a collection. That is the purpose of $asArray() and there is an [entire guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html) dedicated to teaching these concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`$update`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebase-updatekey-data):

```
syncProfile.$update({ "email": "peter@peterpan.com" });
```

Note that `$update` is only available on `$firebase` and not on the FirebaseObject that you get back from `$asObject`. The reason for this is that `$asObject` is really meant as an object that is bound directly to an angular scope. You're not expected to perform updates to it in your own code.

By the way: if the rest of your code is using AngularFire in a similar way, you might consider dropping AngularFire and using [Firebase's JavaScript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/) directly. It is much simpler to use, since it doesn't need to mediate between Firebase and Angular's way of working.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I also 100% agree on the SDK approach, it seems simpler!

Comment: Note that the distinction here is whether or not one is binding data into the view/DOM. AngularFire is great for bindings and takes care of a host of boilerplate and sync edge cases. The SDK level ops are ideal for simple writes and one-directional ops.